# What group made a song (on LP) with backwards message "buy 10 copies of this record"?

Tags: vinyl, identify-this-song

Back in early 90's a friend of mine showed me an LP record with a backwards message on it.

The message was "buy 10 copies of this record". This could be heard with a clearly audible voice when he rotated the record slowly backwards on the turntable.

What group made an LP like this?

Comment: Never heard of anyone actually doing that. But according to [this article](http://ultimateclassicrock.com/judas-priest-suicide-trial/) during their 1990 trial over alleged subliminal messages Judas Priest manager Bill Curbishley said. “If we were going to do that, I’d be saying, ‘Buy seven copies,’ not telling a couple of screwed-up kids to kill themselves."

Comment: There's a list on Wiikipedia, but nothing like that message https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backmasked_messages

Comment: I've heard that too but I can't remember the artist. It was rock or heavy metal music though I am 99% sure

Answer (score 0):

The song "My Band" by the group D12 (released 2004) has the hidden message:

**"Buy this album now. When it gets to the end."**

This is 20 seconds before the end of the track when Eminem does a parody of Kelis's Milkshake called "My Salsa."